# How to hide the text on textbox focus using Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html

I need to hide the text after 
 tag.

My html fields are,

```
 <div id="layered_ajax_loader" style="display: none;">
            <p>
                <img src="./img/loader.gif" alt="" />
                <br />Loading...
            </p>
        </div>



    <form name="chk_disp_page_cnt"  method="get"  onsubmit="return pagn_cal()">
    <input type="hidden" id="hids" value="id_category" />
            <input type="text" id="tst" onfocus="disp_hide_image()"   style="width:50px; height:23px;" />
    </form>

Javascript functions are,


function disp_hide_image()
{

   $('#layered_ajax_loader').show();
   $('layered_ajax_loader').hide();
   $('img[src=".loader.gif"]').hide();
   $("div p:contains('Loading...')").parent('div').hide();
}
```

I need to hide the text  Loading... when the text box is empty . How can I achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this one -

```
<div id="layered_ajax_loader" style="display: none;">
    <p>
        <img src="./img/loader.gif" alt="" />
        <br />Loading...
    </p>
</div>

<form name="chk_disp_page_cnt"  method="get"  onsubmit="return pagn_cal()">
    <input type="hidden" id="hids" value="id_category" />
    <input type="text" id="tst" onfocus="disp_hide_image()"   style="width:50px; height:23px;" />
</form>

function disp_hide_image()
{
    if ('' === $('#tst').val()) {
        $('#layered_ajax_loader').hide();
    } else {
        $('#layered_ajax_loader').show();
    }
}
```

Note: I guess you need to show/hide only the parent div. The loader image will automatically show/hide accordingly.

## UPDATE

I tried with the below code and it worked fine for me.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
<div id="layered_ajax_loader" style="display: none;">
    <p>
        <img src="./img/loader.gif" alt="" />
        <br />Loading...
    </p>
</div>

<form name="chk_disp_page_cnt"  method="get"  onsubmit="return pagn_cal()">
    <input type="hidden" id="hids" value="id_category" />
    <input type="text" id="tst" onkeyup="disp_hide_image()"  style="width:50px; height:23px;" />
</form>

<script>
function disp_hide_image()
{
    if ('' === $('#tst').val()) {
        $('#layered_ajax_loader').hide();
    } else {
        $('#layered_ajax_loader').show();
    }
}
</script>
```

Note: I tried with onkeyup for testing better.

Comment: what problem you are facing exactly.

Comment: the div is not hide on textbox focus .

Comment: How come it is not working for you... I tried and worked absolutely fine for me. I added the one I tried in UPDATE section. You might be facing issue, as you have done onfocus.

Answer (score 1):

```
                <body onload="onLoad()" >
            <div id="layered_ajax_loader" style="display: none;">
                        <p>

                            <br />Loading...
                        </p>
                    </div>



                <form name="chk_disp_page_cnt"  method="get"  id="myid" onsubmit="return pagn_cal()">
                <input type="hidden" id="hids" value="" />
                        <input type="text" id="tst" onfocus="disp_hide_image()"   style="width:50px; height:23px;" />
                </form>
            </body>

            <script>
                var me="";

                function onLoad()
                {
                    console.log("a");
                    me=document.getElementById('hids').value
                    console.log(me);
                    if(me=="")
                    {
                        var body = document.body;
                        document.getElementById('tst').style.display = "none";
                        //body.removeChild(document.getElementById('myid'));
                    }
                }

                function disp_hide_image()
                {

                }
            </script>
```

With plain JavaScript the element can be hidden or an element can be removed from the DOM.

This document I thought was good:
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_display.asp

As well there are a few other stack overflows I saw right away describing both of those techniques. As well the code can be moved into disp_hide_image() as I think you are requesting in comment.

Answer (score 1):

javascript code

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
$("#tst").on("keyup",function ()
{
    if ($(this).val() == "")
    {
        $("#layered_ajax_loader").hide();
    }
    else
    {
        $("#layered_ajax_loader").show();
    }
})
});
```

and you must delete this

**onfocus="disp_hide_image()"**